# ArcMap 10.8.1 export map to PDF doesn't work properly

Tags: arcmap, export, mapping

I have a data frame in ArcMap 10.8.1 with EPSG 25832. There are several shapefiles and one shapefile with measured data, one raster file and one annotation file. All data are included in a map layout. Whenever I export the map to PDF the map frame only includes a kind of raster layer but not the data included in the map layout. Which settings can I make so that the export works properly?

[image: map layout]

[image]

Comment: What were your export settings?  Can you export it successfully to a raster such as a tif or a rasterized pdf?  I think ESRI tech would suggest trying an export to eps as part of its review.  Although it doesn't look like a vector issue you might check the geometry of your vector layers.